# Data won't populate into a subdocument using mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my first question so thanks and sorry if I don't get the format for asking questions perfect. I'm trying to put together a database for a quiz application and I can't quite figure out why I can't get the data from the API I'm trying to put together to populate in the "possibleanswers" array in my database.

[Image of how the data currently comes back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESwsb.png)

Here is my models file.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const possibleAnswersSchema = new Schema({
  a: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  b: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  c: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  d: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const questionSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  question: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  possibleAnswers: [possibleAnswersSchema],
  level: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  questionType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Question = mongoose.model("question", questionSchema);

module.exports = Question;
```

And this is my "seeds" file

```
 await Question.deleteMany();

  const possibleAnswersData = [{ a: "した", b: "じた", c: "しだ", d: "ちた"}];

  const questions = await Question.insertMany(
    {
      description: "What is the reading of the Kanji below?",
      question: "上",
      possibleanswers: possibleAnswersData,
      level: "N5",
      questionType: "kanji",
    }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data)
      }
    });

  console.log("questions seeded");
```

Thanks for all your help!